# Insert commas delimited string into a string column of Athena table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-athena

I created an Amazon Athena table based on CSV in S3. I want to input a row of data with one column that includes commas. But it truncates the string from the commas each time.

For example:

```
insert into table_names (id, key_string)values (1,'{key1=1,key2=3}')
```

Each time, the column key_string only stores `{key1=1`.

I tried use double quote `"{key1=1,key2=3}"`, escape char `\"{key1=1,key2=3}\"`.

They don't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please Edit your question to show how the table was defined. You can obtain this from Athena by clicking the three dots beside a table name and selecting **Generate Create Table DDL**. The table definition tells Athena how to interpret the files and will likely need some modification to tell it that fields are wrapped in quotation marks.

Comment: Try following settings: escapeChar \   quoteChar "      seperatorChar ,       This should let you pass insert into table_names (id, key_string)values (1,"{key1=1,key2=3}")